# Excel Add-in MATLAB library compiler

Tags: excel, matlab, add-in

I'm trying to compile an Excel add-in in Matlab, but I'm having an "Error during packaging":

> No supported compiler or SDK was found. You can install the freely available MinGW-w64 C/C++ compiler; visit http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/install-mingw-support-package.html . For more options, visit http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2016a/win64.html.
>   Error: An error occurred while shelling out to mbuild (error code = -1).
>   Unable to build executable.

In the log it also appear:

> No MEX options file identified; looking for an implicit selection.
>
> No MEX options file identified; looking for an implicit selection.
>
> Did not find installed compiler 'Intel C++ Composer XE 2013 with Microsoft SDK 7.1'.
>
> Did not find installed compiler 'Intel C++ Composer XE 2013 with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010'.
>
> Did not find installed compiler 'Intel C++ Composer XE 2013 with Microsoft Visual Studio 2012'.
>
> Did not find installed compiler 'Intel C++ Composer XE 2013 with Microsoft Visual Studio 2013'.
>
> Did not find installed compiler 'Intel Parallel Studio XE 2015 for C++ with Microsoft SDK 7.1'.
>
> Did not find installed compiler 'Intel Parallel Studio XE 2015 for C++ with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010'.
>
> Did not find installed compiler 'Intel Parallel Studio XE 2015 for C++ with Microsoft Visual Studio 2012'.
>
> Did not find installed compiler 'Intel Parallel Studio XE 2015 for C++ with Microsoft Visual Studio 2013'.
>
> Did not find installed compiler 'Intel Parallel Studio XE 2015 for C++ with Microsoft Visual Studio 2015'.
>
> Did not find installed compiler 'Intel Parallel Studio XE 2016 for C++ with Microsoft SDK 7.1'.
>
> Did not find installed compiler 'Intel Parallel Studio XE 2016 for C++ with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010'.
>
> Did not find installed compiler 'Intel Parallel Studio XE 2016 for C++ with Microsoft Visual Studio 2012'.
>
> Did not find installed compiler 'Intel Parallel Studio XE 2016 for C++ with Microsoft Visual Studio 2013'.
>
> Did not find installed compiler 'Intel Parallel Studio XE 2016 for C++ with Microsoft Visual Studio 2015'.
>
> Found installed compiler 'MinGW64 Compiler (C++)'.
>
> Did not find installed compiler 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2010'.
>
> Did not find installed compiler 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2012'.
>
> Did not find installed compiler 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Professional'.
>
> Did not find installed compiler 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Professional'.

I've all Visual Studio Versions installed on my machine.

Anyone with solution for that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution.

Install Visual Studio (in case I installed the 2015 pro version) in custom mode and add all C++ itens.